# Related Drop down list

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am working with Conditional Fields Contact Form 7. I would like to load values of a Drop down list based on value of another drop down list. My Code is like below

```
<label> Division*
[select division first_as_label “Choose your Division” “BARISHAL” “CHITTAGONG” “DHAKA” “KHULNA” “MYMENSINGH” “RAJSHAHI” “RANGPUR” “SYLHET”] </label>

<label> District*
[select district first_as_label “Choose your District”
[group disrtict]
"BARISHAL" "BARGUNA" "BHOLA" "JHALAKATHI" "PIROJPUR" "POTUAKHALI"] </label>
[/group]
```

But this is not working.

Comment: you cannot use conditional logic with just CF7 plugin. if I recall correctly, there is a different 3rd party (not from the CF7 developer), which adds the facility you required. I dun remember the name correctly, but you'll be able to find it after a quick search

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Conditional Contact Form 7 plugin, for each values in your first dropdown you need to create a corresponding dropdown field,

`[select first-dropdown "chose a value" "value 1" "value 2"]
[group dropdown-value-1]
[select value-1-dropdown "chose option for value 1" "value 1a" "value 1b"]
[/group]
[group dropdown-value-2]
[select value-2-dropdown "chose option for value 2" "value 2a" "value 2b"]
[/group]

`You then need to setup your visibility rules, and to show`dropdown-value-1` group when 'value 1' is selected in the first dropdpwn and so on. See this [tutorial](https://conditional-fields-cf7.bdwm.be/conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7-tutorial/) which explains all the steps in details.